# JOOQ: How to create drop columns query?

Tags: sql, jooq

Looks like it's impossible to drop more than one column.

```
DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL).alterTable("table_name").dropColumn(field("column_name"))
```

It returns AlterTableDropStep and it's a final step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pending feature request to allow for dropping more than one column in a single statement: [#5319](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5319) (and also for adding more than one column in a single statement: [#5318](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5318)).

As of jOOQ 3.10, you will have to run several statements instead of a single one.